# Motor Driver IC - Motor Supply with Capacitor in Series

Tags: voltage, capacitor, pcb-design, series, motor-controller

I'm trying to figure out what should be the voltage rating of the capacitor in series to VHS pin of TMC2660 driver. And also how is the voltage of the VHS pin is calculated for 24V motor supply voltage ?

"The Power Mosfet Stage" part of the datasheet states that

> The high-side gate driver voltage is supplied by the
>   VS and the VHS pin. VHS is more negative than VS and allows opening the VS referenced high-side MOSFET. The high-side driver supplies VS to the P channel MOSFET gate to close the MOSFET and VHS to open it. The effective low-side gate voltage is roughly 5V; the effective high-side gate voltage is roughly 8V.

VHS pin(35.) connected in series capacitor and then the motor supply voltage(V+). The driver supports 8-30V supply voltage, so I'll consider giving 24V to motor supply. The circuit in the datasheet:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From table 2.2 of the [datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2660_datasheet.pdf), the voltage on VHS is 10V below the motor supply voltage.  So that would be 14V for your case.

That suggests the max voltage across the capacitor is also 10V. Figure 3.1 of the datasheet confirms this by showing a 16V capacitor.

[image]